# What is the use of "的" in "辞的职"?

Tags: grammar

In 汉语口语速成: 基础篇 pp. 147, there's a sentence:

> 爱珍： 你学习汉语是为了工作?
>
> 左拉： 可以说是吧，不过，现在我失业了，来中国之前**辞的职**。

I understand that "辞职" means "to resign", but I don't understand why "的" is inserted between them. What's the use of "的" here?

I suspect that "辞职" is a separable verb. According to Wiktionary, "辞" means "to dismiss". "职" could be from the word "职业", meaning "profession".

If it is, then could "辞的职" here mean "辞我的职业"?

Comment: Almost exactly the same question here: http://lang-8.com/707382/journals/181151635036180227089908067059150999248

Comment: @user3306356 Thank you. So is this all about "是……的" construction? ”来中国之前是我辞的职“ seems makes sense to me.

Comment: You could also say, 来中国之前辞职的，it means the same.

Comment: @zyy Thanks for pointing that out. "来中国之前辞职的" also makes sense to me. At first, I was also expecting to put "的" after "辞职", instead of the middle of it.

Comment: @Reynaldi You are absolutely welcome!

Comment: 这句话侧重点在时间上，辞职的时间是在来中国前，而不是说他在来中国前做了一件辞职的事情。Point of the sentence is the moment he resigned. 来中国前辞职 can also  be explained as "you will resign before you go to China", so additional “的”  is used to suppress ambiguity and implies you HAVE resigned even though no "我现在失业了".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

辞职: resign; quit the job;

辞： quit; take leave; resign; dismiss;

职（in 辞职）is short for **职位**(not 职业)： position；

So, 辞职 can be interpreted as: ***quit your position*** or just ***resign***.

辞职 is a 离合词，so it's separable. Phrases like 辞的职, 吃的饭, 说的话, and etc denote **that you have done something at sometime or at some place** and usually they are followed or preceded by a prepositional phrase describing time or position.

In your example,  来中国之前(before coming to China) is the time and 辞的职 is what you have done(quit your job). So, 来中国之前辞的职 is **quit my job before coming to China**.

More examples:

> 我在家里吃的饭 // I ate my meal at home.
>
> 这是我昨天在会议上讲的话 // This is what I said at the meeting yesterday.

Comment: Oh, I thought "职" is a short for "职业", because this word is also used on the book. Glad to know that.

Comment: @Reynaldi, 职业 is occupation.  职位 is position. You quit your position, not your occupation. So, it should be short for 职位.

Comment: This "的" is different from other like"我的"，“这是我讲的话”, see the answer below.

Comment: @XL_at_China it's 讲的话，not 我的.

Comment: @XL_at_China I don't understand. Which example has the meaning of "我的" are you referring to?

Comment: @Reynaldi like “这是我的”，“这是我昨天在会议上讲的话。”

Comment: @dan itmakes no difference。if“ 我在家里吃的饭” is like 昨天你在哪里吃的饭？ -----我在家里吃的饭“ ，this ”的“ isdifferrent from ”的“ in 这是我讲的话

Answer (score 0):

I think '的' here is used to emphasis that something has already been done. So, '辞的职' means 'have already resigned'.

Answer (score 0):

“来中国之前辞的职” means it is before I came to China when I had quited my position. "的"means the action already have happened or begin, and stress some part of sentence,like time, place,object,subject,etc. Especially, the speaker presupposes that the listener has already known the event has happened. and it is usually attached to the verb. This "的" isdifferent from other like"我的"，“这是我讲的话”

Comment: Are you saying that the meaning of "的" in "这是我讲的话" and "这是我昨天在会议上讲的话" are different?

Comment: @Reynaldi, no, I mean “的” in “来中国之前辞的职”  is different from other like"我的"，“这是我讲的话”， many researchers think it is a different  “的”

Comment: If anyone suspect what I say, you may find some articles to read, Actually, "的" is a word with complex usages

Comment: Hmm, so "来中国之前辞的职" is not a "是……的" construction? That means if I said "来中国之前我辞的职", is it have the same meaning with "来中国之前是我辞的职"?

Comment: At least I can learn that this "的" in the sentence is definitely not a possessive pronoun (e.g `我的家`, `我的说话`), that's for sure.

Comment: @Reynaldi, no, "是" has to be inserted before the stressed part， in 来中国之前我辞的职" may transformed into"我是来中国之我辞的职"。 "来中国之前是我辞的职" is an invalid sentence, “我” is impossible to be stressed.